# python 3.6.3 index error for list of undeclared length

Tags: python, syntax-error

So I'm building a program to generate a histogram from a given list of values, the main number crunching bit looks like this:

```
x=[] #declare x list(unnecessary?)
i=0 #declare i (unnecessary?)
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    comp = data[i] #grab 'i'th data value
    for j in range(0, bins): #determine which bin data point belongs
        lorng=lo+(j*binwidth)
        hirng=lo+((j+1)*binwidth)
        if comp==lo:
            x[0]+=1 #increment lowest value bin for lowest value data
        if comp > lorng and comp <= hirng: 
            x[j]+=1 #increment bin for data in a given range
print(x)
```

Unfortunately i am getting a list index out of range error on`x[0]+=1`. Do I need to declare the list length? It seems from other threads I don't need to do that.

edit: I've changed `x[]` to`x=np.zeroes(shape=(1,bins)`, but now it is throwing an invalid syntax error on `i=0` so i cant check it

Comment: `x` is initially an empty list, which does not support any indexing at all. Also, Python uses 0 indexing, so `x[0]` would be the first item in the list (if it contained any items and supported indexing). Does this have to be in pure Python or can you use numpy?

Comment: I can use numpy, I have it imported but unused presently, if I declare `x[]` via numpy would that solve the issue? I've only got a vague understanding of lists.. i got the same error with `x[0]` the 1 was just a test.

Comment: No, using an array in itself would not fix the issue. To continue with your approach, you'd need to initialise the list with the correct number of elements beforehand; `x = [0 for i in range(10)]` where 10 is your number of bins, for example. But numpy provides fast methods for binning data.

Comment: no need to declare start value of range if it is `0`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is an empty list, which does not support any kind of indexing. That's why `x[0]+=1` gives an error.

Since you're open to using `numpy`, you can achieve the same kind of effect using [`histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

```
import numpy as np

values = np.random.randint(0, 101, 1000)
hist = np.histogram(values, bins=10)
print(hist)
```

This creates a list of 1000 random numbers between 0 and 100, and then divides them into 10 bins. If you wanted to do this in pure python, you'd have to initialise your list with the correct number of indices beforehand: `x = [0 for i in range(num_bins)]` (or similiar).

To address your questions in code comments:

1. Yes, with your approach you need to define `x` first (as discussed).
2. No, there is no need to declare `i`, `for i in range(0, len(data)):` takes care of that.

EDIT:

Just noticed your edit made while I was working on this answer:

1. Your `SyntaxError` on `i = 0` is actually caused by the line before: `x=np.zeroes(shape=(1,bins)` is missing a closing parens.
2. You don't want `shape=(1, bins)` since that would give you a 2D array. If you wanted to initialise `x` in this way, instead of my python approach, use `x = np.zeros(bins)`.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help, that parenthesis issue was why I just left it for a bit. I also appreciate the histogram command tip, however this is basically practice so I am trying to do this the longish way. It's (mostly) working now, just not quite depositing numbers in bins properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your list doesn't have anything at the beginning. So you need to zerofill it to access all the element by index without inserting them explicitly.

```
x=[0] * bins

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    comp = data[i]
    for j in range(0, bins):
        lorng=lo+(j*binwidth)
        hirng=lo+((j+1)*binwidth)
        if comp==lo:
            x[0]+=1 #increment lowest value bin for lowest value data
        if comp > lorng and comp <= hirng: 
            x[j]+=1 #increment bin for data in a given range
print(x)
```

It's worth noting that `x = [0] * bins` initializes the list `x` with `bins` zeroes.